# Trouble Importing CSV to MYSQL using Navicat - Believe its a Unicode Error

Tags: mysql, csv, unicode, import, navicat

I'm having a tough time getting this large import working from a CSV file. It keeps only loading some of the rows.

Here is the log file: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u6iOFcI0cE4S5JmM1LNe-m5s2LV_Q0liQZkx8j95tCY/edit?usp=sharing

Here is the Data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AramgOJO7c-XdGloc2FwUnh4eWl2QzBkYzNKdlpTUGc&usp=sharing

Any help would be appreciate; I'm at a total loss.

Comment: I just imported the same data via Navicat without issue... What type is the field you're loading that data into?

Comment: Very odd @colbydauph. Lets retrace my steps a bit more. I'm loading it into a Char(100) field. The grid of course was originally xls saved as a CSV file. When using the import wizard on Navicat I chose CSV and then uploaded the file with Unicode (UTF-8) as the Encoding. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, Interesting. I just downloaded the spreadsheet from google docs as a CSV and it imported just fine. I have to do this very often thought, could anyone have a clue why it is not working from a CSV saved from XLS??

Comment: If you host the original csv somewhere I'll try importing it that way and see what kind of errors I get.

Comment: @colbydauph sorry for taking so long to send this over. Here is a link to the csv file: https://copy.com/CXAWFMWqJBFGs9yu